# Solving differential equation for a single time in loop with matlab

Tags: matlab, controls, ode, differential-equations

I have a Mechanical system with following equation:

`xdot = Ax+ Bu`

I want to solve this equation in a loop because in every step I need to update u but solvers like `ode45` or `lsim` solving the differential equation for a time interval.

```
 for i = 1:10001
    if  x(i,:)>= Sin1 &  x(i,:)<=Sout2
        U(i,:) = Ueq - (K*(S/Alpha))
    else
        U(i,:) = Ueq - (K*S)
    end
   % [y(i,:),t,x(i+1,:)]=lsim(sys,U(i,:),(time=i/1000),x(i,:));
   or %[t,x] = ode45(@(t,x)furuta(t,x,A,B,U),(time=i/1000),x)
end
```

Do I have another ways to solve this equation in a loop for a single time(Not single time step).

Comment: I don't get your explanation. I think you should explain more clearly what is the question. Also, try to put your complete program (or at least a working program)

Comment: I don't want to solve the equation for time intervals. I want to solve it for 0,0.001,0,002 separately. Because in every step I need to update U and X.
If I use ode45 it will solve my equation for time intervals and my code cannot update U or x in every step.

Comment: I think I have a solution, but I need some clarifications.  You are performing a vector comparison `x(i,:)>= Sin1`; are you trying to adjust `U` row-by-row this way?  You are saving all previous `U` vectors; is this storage required?

Comment: Yes. you understand the problem correct. I am performing a vector comparison and yes I am trying to adjust U row by row in every step.
It is better to have U but x is more important than U.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of methods for updating and storing data across function calls.
For the ODE suite, I've come to like what is called "closures" for doing that.
A closure is basically a nested function accessing or modifying a variable from its parent function.

The code below makes use of this feature by wrapping the right-hand side function passed to [`ode45`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html) and the [`'OutputFcn'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/odeset.html#odeoutputfcn) in a parent function called `odeClosure()`.

You'll notice that I am using logical-indexing instead of an `if`-statement.
Vectors in `if`-statements will only be true if all elements are true and vice-versa for false.
Therefore, I create a logical array and use it to make the denominator either `1` or `Alpha` depending on the signal value for each row of `x`/`U`.

The `'OutputFcn'` `storeU()` is called after a successful time step by `ode45`.
The function grows the `U` storage array and updates it appropriately.
The array `U` will have the same number of columns as the number of solution points requested by [`tspan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ode45.html#f92-1027226) (12 in this made-up example).
If a successful full step leaps over any requested points, the function is called with intermediate all requested times and their associated solution values (so `x` may be rectangular and not just a vector); this is why I used `bsxfun` in `storeU` and not in `rhs`.

Example function:

```
function [sol,U] = odeClosure()

    % Initilize
%     N     = 10          ;
    A     = [ 0,0,1.0000,0; 0,0,0,1.0000;0,1.3975,-3.7330,-0.0010;0,21.0605,-6.4748,-0.0149];
    B     = [0;0;0.6199;1.0752 ] ;
    x0    = [11;11;0;0];
    K     = 100;
    S     = [-0.2930;4.5262;-0.5085;1.2232];
    Alpha = 0.2          ;
    Ueq   = [0;-25.0509;6.3149;-4.5085];
    U     = Ueq;
    Sin1  = [-0.0172;-4.0974;-0.0517;-0.2993];
    Sout2 = [0.0172 ; 4.0974; 0.0517; 0.2993];

    % Solve
    options = odeset('OutputFcn', @(t,x,flag) storeU(t,x,flag));
    sol     = ode45(@(t,x) rhs(t,x),[0,0.01:0.01:0.10,5],x0,options);


    function xdot = rhs(~,x)

        between = (x >= Sin1) &  (x <= Sout2);
        uwork   = Ueq - K*S./(1 + (Alpha-1).*between);
        xdot    = A*x + B.*uwork;

    end

    function status = storeU(t,x,flag)

        if isempty(flag)
            % grow array
            nAdd      = length(t)           ;
            iCol      = size(U,2) + (1:nAdd);
            U(:,iCol) = 0                   ;

            % update U
            between   = bsxfun(@ge,x,Sin1) & bsxfun(@le,x,Sout2);
            U(:,iCol) = Ueq(:,ones(1,nAdd)) - K*S./(1 + (Alpha-1).*between);
        end

        status = 0;
    end

end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and It is probably true, however when I use my own inputs the error occurs. My inputs are:
`A     =[ 0 0 1.0000 0; 0 0 0 1.0000;0 1.3975 -3.7330 -0.0010;0 21.0605 -6.4748 -0.0149]     ;
    B     = [0;0;0.6199;1.0752 ]    ;
    x0    = [11 11 0 0]  ;
    K     = 100        ;
    S     = [-0.2930    4.52620.2930    4.5262   -0.5085    1.2232]        ;
    Alpha = 0.2          ;
    Ueq   = [0  -25.0509    6.3149   -4.5085]   ;
    U     = Ueq         ;
    Sin1  = [-0.0172   -4.0974   -0.0517   -0.2993]        ;
    Sout2 = [0.0172    4.0974    0.0517    0.2993]        ;`

Comment: Assuming you `S` was a copy mistake and taking it to be `[-0.2930;4.5262;-0.5085;1.2232];` and making all the vectors column vectors, my script works.  (When dealing with arrays, understanding shape is essential in MATLAB.)